# How to get list element number by class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, find

I have this list:

```
<ul>
   <li>data</li>
   <li>data</li>
   <li>data</li>
   <li class="focus">data</li>
   <li>data</li>
   <li>data</li>
</ul>
```

I need to get the element numer with class focus, and change it, so i do this:

```
  btn.on('click', function(){
      var number_of_element = js_films_list_top.find('li.focus').length;
      js_films_list_bottom.find('li').length(number_of_element).addClass('focus');
  });
```

I guess the lenght method is no good for this, but which is better to use? Can you help me?

Comment: please explain what you want the code to do in words. The code makes no sense

Comment: that's way im asking for help

Comment: @ŁukaszBorawski: Help with what? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Ok, you have some right but, before I ask check the API, sometimes it is difficult to find the right solution, asking for help is a much easier way to do it to learn something more than mindless drudgery of documentation. Next time I do not ask about it because I know how to solve this problem, I'll deal with it quickly without wasting time. In this way I will be able in the future to help someone else ...

Comment: *"...asking for help is a much easier...than mindless drudgery of documentation..."* I'm sorry, but if that's your attitude, you need to stop now and find something else to do. It's terribly selfish of you to say that it's not worth your time and effort to learn for yourself, so I'll occupy someone else's time.

Comment: I did not want to say that I do not want to look, and I'm going to cut corners, asking the SO receives support and faster response, the faster the faster I can learn and grow, sometimes it's hard to spend the time to read the documentation for hours and still do not understand it and I'm therefore very grateful for your or other users help, you also at some stage of development in jquery probably did not know anything

Comment: Yes, I started out knowing nothing, and I worked very hard on my own to learn. I never asked a question until I had spent much time doing my own research. Only when I had exhausted all avenues did I ask for help. In taking this approach, I would learn 10 other things while trying to figure out the one. Because of this, my knowledge increased much more rapidly that it would have if I didn't put forth such efforts. Not knowing is excusable. Not trying is not.

Comment: OK, I'll take your words for the heart and I promise improve, sorry again and thx for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for `.eq()` and `.index()`:

```
var index = js_films_list_top.find('li.focus').index();
js_films_list_bottom.find('li').eq(index).addClass('focus');
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry i know, this was a stupid question, my bad, but in that case eq() not proved to be good, and I do not fell like to use index()